# For loop in 2 arrays of same size gives ValueError

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7

I'm trying to go through 2 arrays of same length in a `for` loop, but I'm getting a

> ValueError: too many values to unpack

Here is the code generating the error :

```
test = [1, 0, 5, 2, 6, 3, 4]
names = ['patient_map_id', 'birth_date', 'age_in_years_num', 
         'sex_cd', 'vital_status', 'event_map_id', 'start_date']

for col_num, name in (test, names) :
    #do stuff
```

If I'm not mistaken, there should be a way to do this but I don't see where the mistake comes from

Comment: It means "sex code". for 'M' or 'F'

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) the lists before you iterate through them. A `for` loop cannot iterate through multiple iterables as such.
The `zip` function combines all the passed iterables into a single iterator.

**Note:** The returned iterator is only as long as the shortest list passed to it.

```
# code

for col_num, name in zip(test, names):
    #do stuff
```

Comment: Oh. well that seems to work fine! thanks I'll keep it in mind next time!